# R: Referencing a matched string in sub

Tags: regex, r

How can I reference a matched string (or captured group) in R so as to append in a `sub()`. For instance, I would do it like this in `sed` to append a `'d'` to the match

```
echo "66xx" | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]/&d/g'
66dxx
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> sub("([0-9][0-9])(.*)","\\1d\\2", "66xx")
[1] "66dxx"
```

Comment: I see, it is the escaping of the backslash I was missing. Thanks